# There are cross signs all over the google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google maps api and there are cross signs on map. How to fix this?

Comment: Most likely, you have zoomed too much. Try zooming out.

Comment: No, it is drawing on all zoom levels.

Comment: If that is not the case then you need to check that the apikey is correct and generated from the certificate you have used to sign the applicaion,

Comment: No, it is not about signing. I signed it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is `mapView.setStreetView(true);` I don't know why, but when I remove this line they dissappered.

Answer (score 2):

In Wrox Example both satelligh and steetview are set to ture.
Only one view can be set to true at a time.

If you set both then you will see cross mark. Not a very helpfull exception message :)

Answer (score 0):

To use google maps in your android application you should obtain maps api key and paste it in layout definition.

Sample layout code

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

Please remember that api key will be different for production and dev environments as you would use probably different certificates to sign application (eclipse automatically use debug certificate to sign any application deployed in dev mode).

I've faced also issue on testing applications signed with debug certificate on real devices, on emulator map was showed properly whereas on real device I must use other, non debug certificate and install application manually (not using eclipse).

Detailed instructions how to obtain your API key are provided at [this site](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Comment: Of course I am signing the application (as I said on my comment).